# Is there any method for `WebGLRenderingContext` as in `CanvasRenderingContext2D.getImageData()`?

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

Suppose we can get `ImageData` from `CanvasRenderingContext2D`.

```
var element = document.getElementById('someCanvas');
var context = element.getContext('2d');
var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
```

I wonder if it can be done with `WebGLRenderingContext` as well?

```
var element = document.getElementById('someCanvas');
var context = element.getContext('webgl');
/* Get image data ... */
```

Thank a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work exactly the same but you can get all of the pixels in the drawing buffer using [`WebGLRenderingContext.readPixels`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/readPixels). Make sure you call it *before* you exit the event that actually rendered the pixels.

```
var context = element.getContext('webgl');
var pixels = new Uint8Array(context.drawingBufferWidth * context.drawingBufferHeight * 4);
context.readPixels(
  0, 
  0, 
  context.drawingBufferWidth, 
  context.drawingBufferHeight, 
  context.RGBA, 
  context.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
  pixels);
```

Comment: you don't need to preserve the drawing buffer. You just need to make sure you call readPixels before you exit the event that rendered the pixels.

Comment: @gman My mistake. I read that somewhere a long time ago. Edited.